# Query Google GA API return different results without sample data

Tags: google-analytics

I run one query in ga query explorer (https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/query-explorer/) and the return no contains sampled data.

But when i run same query change the date filter i get a different result, more data is returned. Why?

PS. In both query no contains sampled data. My account isn't premium.

First query with less data
[image: First query with less data]

Second query with more data
[image: Second query with more data]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because its about how to analyze Google analytics data and is not programing related.  might be better suited for http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/

Comment: because, Its obvious that for different date ranges you will have some different data